# Sharing boolean value between threads without locks in C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have two threads, call them a server thread and a computation thread.  The server thread starts the computation thread, passing it a pointer to a boolean variable, the "stop flag".  When the server thread sets the stop flag to true, the computation thread should exit its computation loop and return from the run function.

My question is, is there any way to **safely share that flag** between the two threads, **without using any sort of locks** (mutexes, semaphores, etc)?  Keep in mind:

- Flag will be set to true once
- Flag will never be set back to false once set to true
- There is only one server thread, and only one computation thread

I define "safely" in this case to be any approach in which setting the flag to true in server thread is **guaranteed to reflect a true value** in the computation thread in a reasonable amount of time. (If your answer includes the word "eventually", it probably doesn't satisfy "a reasonable amount of time").

I am interested in both portable and non-portable solutions.  I run on a Linux platform, but have some flexibility beyond that: GCC, Clang, kernel versions, C-standard versions, etc.

Comment: That reasonable amount of time depends on the contents of the computation loop.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, defining the variable as `volatile` is enough.

With a single write, corruption is not possible.

There's no guarantee about the time it would take the write to be visible, but you don't need one.

`volatile` prevents harmful optimizations - if the compiler sees that a variable isn't modified, it may assume that it doesn't need to reread it from memory. `volatile` prevents this.

Comment: No, you also have to make it clear to the compiler that it *must* backup the variable in memory.

Comment: @JensGustedt, `volatile` does this.

Comment: I don't see where `volatile` does this. `register` and `volatile` are by no means contradictory, and the compiler has well the right not to back up a volatile variable in memory. The only thing that `volatile` inhibits are certain assumptions about the value of the variable.

Comment: @JensGustedt, `volatile` inhibits assumptions about how a variable is modified (see C99 6.7.3-6). If not backing it with memory causes writes by another thread not to take effect, then it must back it with memory. If it can somehow keep it in a register while assuring writes from another thread do take effect - then there's no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring the flag (your `bool`) as `volatile` is enough here. This just disables caching of this variable and every read is guaranteed to return the current value.

Answer (score 2):

The correct data type for that purpose is the new type `atomic_flag` and accompanying functions from the recent C standard C11. Most compilers don't have that yet, but have similar things that you can use to emulate this. E.g gcc and relatives have `__sync_lock_test_and_set` and `__sync_lock_release` for the same purpose.

Just declaring a variable `volatile` as others suggest is *not* sufficient in general. Although rare for `int` or `_Bool`, a read or write from or to such a variable could be partial if it is located across cache boundaries. This could e.g result that a higher order bit of the variable appears to be set (resulting in an interpretation as `true`).

```
/* in file scope */
int work_has_been_initiated = 0;


/* inside the threads */
if (!__sync_lock_test_and_set(&work_has_been_initiated, 1)) {
   /* do the work, here */
}
```

If this sematic is not strong enough for your purpose, you could use other atomic operations such as `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap`.

Comment: Could you give an example using __sync_lock_test_and_set and  __sync_lock_release?

Comment: This is an overkill - if only one thread modifies the flag, it doesn't need atomic operations. Though I admit sometimes overkills are better, in case the code gets more complicated and nobody bothers to update the synchronization.

Comment: @ugoren, no that is not overkill. On most architectures this will result in very simple assembler code, but there are architectures that need special care for these things. It is the compiler writer's job to know when this is the case and produce the appropriate code.